# Perl Regex - How to find all digits in a String that are preceded by a defined String

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

I am trying to find all the digits following a certain String pattern using a Perl compatible Regex.  For example, I want to find the number "123" but only if it is preceded by the String "me". ex: this is a String me123, this123, me12234.

This should return "123", "12234".

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@matches = ( $input =~ /(?<=me)(\d+)/g );
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@matches = ( $input =~ /me(\d+)/g );
```